# My Intent.Extras is always null when I click a notification. How can I get the Intent data?

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, xamarin, android-notifications

I'm unable to get the Intent's Extras data when I view a notification. The following is how I build the notification, and the intent data that I pass into it. Is there something wrong with it? I've seen other examples very similar to this that appeared to work.

```
    protected override void OnMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
            // irrelevant stuff removed

            string title = "Notification";
            string message = "The Notification Message";

            Bundle valuesForActivity = new Bundle();
            valuesForActivity.PutInt("panelId", (int)panelId);

            Intent pendingIntent = new Intent(context, typeof (TabContainer));
            pendingIntent.PutExtras(valuesForActivity);
            pendingIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
            pendingIntent.PutExtra("panelId", (int)panelId);

            //neither PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent or PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent works
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, pendingIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
            //PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, pendingIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

            var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
            builder.SetContentTitle(title);
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.icon24);
                builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(context.Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Drawable.icon96)));
                builder.SetContentText(message);
            builder.SetContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
            builder.SetTicker(title);
            builder.SetVibrate(new long[] { 100, 200, 300 });

            var notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
            notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
    }
```

Then in the TabContainer activity, I never have the data I need:

```
public class TabContainer : TabActivity
{
    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();

        int panelId = Intent.GetIntExtra("panelId", 0); // always 0

        var extras = Intent.Extras; // always null

    }
}
```

Comment: there should be a OnNewIntent somewhere ? (at least there is in actual android)

Comment: what is panelId? check if that can be int or not, while putting into intent

Comment: `OnNewIntent` appears to be the solution.  I've overridden it in TabContainer and it's firing, and the `Intent` object contains the data I need.

Comment: Cool. Please answer your own question and accept that answer so this question is removed from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked:

```
public class TabContainer : TabActivity
{
    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        try
        {
            var panelId = intent.GetIntExtra("panelId", 0);

            // do the things I need with panelId.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DealWithError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```